# algorithmic problem - Combining overlapping ranges

Tags: algorithms

I'm looking for an idea to efficiently solve following problem:

I have a set of pairs of ranges (range = a pair of numbers), each range is unique (but has same size) e.g.

```
[
 [(0,6),(34,40)],
 [(1,7),(35,41)],
 [(3,9),(12,18)],
 [(2,8),(36,42)],
 [(13,19),(22,28)],
 [(23,29),(14,20)]   
]
```

Now I'd like to combine pairs of ranges, if ranges are overlapping e.g.

```
[(0,6),(34,40)] overlaps with [(1,7),(35,41)] -result-> [(0,7),(34,41)]
```

So as a result for above set I'd like to get (now each pair may have ranges of different size)

```
[
 [(0,8),(34,42)],
 [(3,9),(12,18)],
 [(13,20),(22,29)]
]
```

The set might be pretty big, I'd like to avoid quadratic complexity if possible.

**EDIT:** My best idea so far (in Python) is below. I'd like to know if you know a better(faster) way. Also I'm not sure if my idea of removing already combined pairs is valid:

```
def ranges_overlap(range1, range2):
    return range1[0] < range2[1] and range2[0] < range1[1]


def combine_pairs(pair1, pair2):
    return [(min(r1[0], r2[0]), max(r1[1], r2[1])) for r1, r2 in zip(pair1, pair2)]


def combine_overlapping_pairs(pairs):
    combined = []
    while pairs:
        pair1 = pairs.pop()
        already_combined = []
        for pair2 in pairs:
            for pair2_perm in itertools.permutations(pair2):
                does_overlap = True
                for range1, range2 in zip(pair1, pair2_perm):
                    if not ranges_overlap(range1, range2):
                        does_overlap = False
                        break

                if does_overlap:
                    pair1 = combine_pairs(pair1, pair2_perm)
                    already_combined.append(pair2)
                    break

        combined.append(pair1)
        # Not sure if I can do that
        for pair in already_combined:
            pairs.remove(pair)

    return combined
```

Comment: Why didn't `(0,8)` and `(3,9)` combine?  Do both pairs have to overlap?

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt yes, both pairs have to overlap

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I've appended my best idea to question, is there any faster solution?

Comment: @miszczu: if both pairs have to overlap, where is the `pairs_overlap` test in your code? I see only a `ranges_overlap` test.

Comment: Interesting question. I've been thinking about this. Can you clarify something? You can have a pair of ranges A that overlaps B and B overlaps some C, but A doesn't overlap C. I'm assuming in this case, however, you do want A, B, and C to ultimately be combined. If this is the case, this gets kind of nasty because then I think there are also cases where A overlaps B, but that C only overlaps A+B - not either individually, meaning A+B has to be found first. Does this seem right?

Comment: Another tactic you might try is to think about the two pairs as perpendicular segments, thus defining a rectangle. Then you might be able to leverage "union of rectangles" types of questions (since that is what overlap of both ranges could also mean), of which there are many in computational geometry...

Comment: Stackoverflow already have a few questions on QuadTree implementations in Python (anything from SciPy to pure Python, and more). Since your list is initialized from the beginning, you don't need to worry about the issue of tree rebalancing. That is, you can just build the tree upfront. Quadtree, R-tree and k-D tree are examples of multi-dimensional spatial search trees. If you aren't already familiar with this concept, you should learn it first. It is not something reducible to single-dimensional search unless your data size is known and fixed (i.e. reducible to a constant).

Comment: These are rectangles, and the combining operation is equivalent to finding the bounding rectangle. Finding overlaps efficiently is exactly the problem that R-trees set out to solve. If there are a lot of these, and a lot of them combine, I would need a strong reason not to just use an R-tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third time's the charm, I hope.  I combined my original idea to sort the list first with Snowman's suggestion of using set theory.  The basic algorithm is:

- Sort the pairs in lexicographic order by the first range.
- Group adjacent pairs by if just the first ranges overlap.  I prove below that lexicographically sorted ranges will never overlap without being adjacent, which allows this step to be done in `O(n)`.  This creates sets where the first ranges overlap.
- *Within* each of those sets, sort again by the second range, and group by if the second ranges overlap.  This splits sets where the first ranges overlap into sets where the second ranges also overlap.
- Within each set of sets, repeatedly combine pairs until you have one merged pair.

Here's an `O(n log n)` implementation in Haskell:

```hs
import Data.List
import Data.Tuple

type Range = (Int, Int)
type RangePair = (Range, Range)

rangesOverlap :: Range -> Range -> Bool
rangesOverlap (a,b) (c,d) =
  c <= a && a <= d ||
  c <= b && b <= d ||
  a <= c && c <= b ||
  a <= d && d <= b

pairsOverlap :: RangePair -> RangePair -> Bool
pairsOverlap (a, b) (c, d) = rangesOverlap a c

combineRanges :: Range -> Range -> Range
combineRanges (a,b) (c,d) = (min a c, max b d)

combinePairs :: RangePair -> RangePair -> RangePair
combinePairs (a, b) (c, d) = (combineRanges a c, combineRanges b d)

combineOverlapping :: [RangePair] -> [RangePair]
combineOverlapping = map swap . concat . 
  map (combineSets. makeSet . map swap) . makeSet 
  where makeSet = groupBy pairsOverlap . sort
        combineSets = map (foldl1 combinePairs)
```

We wish to prove that if
  the ranges are lexicographically sorted, all the overlapping ranges will
  occur in adjacent rows.  Assume a counterexample exists where overlapping
  ranges are not in adjacent rows.  It will take the form of:

```
(a, b)
(c, d)
(e, f)
```

where `(a,b)` and `(e,f)` overlap with each other, but `(c,d)` does not overlap with either.

In order for `(c,d)` not to overlap with `(a,b)`, `d` must be less than `a` or `b`
  must be less than `c`. `c <= d` because it is a range, and `a <= c` because of
  lexicographical sorting, therefore `d >= a`.  `e <= b` because of overlapping,
  and `c <= e` because of lexicographical sorting, therefore `c <= b`.  Therefore,
  if `(a,b)` and `(e,f)` overlap, then `(a,b)` and `(c,d)` always overlap, and no
  counterexample exists.

Comment: Not quite. [(1,3),(8,10)],[(2,4),(6,7)],[(3,4),(9,11)] - the first and third overlap but the first and second doesn't even though they're in sorted order.

Comment: That's an excellent catch.  I think there's still a solution in there somewhere if you run it twice, once sorted on the first tuple and once on the second.  The merge is tricky, though.  I'll ponder on it.

Comment: Hrmm... This sorting thing feels like a trap. A hunch tells me that the two pairs may need to be treated as independent dimensions, so a topological sort or something may be needed to fully make it go...

Comment: See my new answer, I believe looking at this using set theory will produce more accurate results, but the performance might not be optimal.

Comment: He already knows how to solve it quadratically.  You have to sort it *somehow* to do better.

Comment: I think I managed to get the best of both worlds with my last edit, @Snowman.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it looks promising. I'll try to implement it in Python

Comment: I think you can end up with cases where a link appears to exist because of the first range overlap, but because the second doesn't overlap, the last step/condition doesn't work: "repeatedly combine pairs until you have one merged pair". So suppose you have the following three items: A:[(0,1),(102,103)], B:[(1,2),(100,101)], C:[(2,3),(102,103)]. Step 1 - sort gives A,B,C. Step 2 - first grouping yields one group (A,B,C). Step 3 - order by second pair/group, gives (A,C) and (B). Step 4 - (A,C) can't collapse. In this case B is the "false link". I don't know Haskell, so did I miss something?

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  I think you would have to keep alternating which range you split on until no splits occur, because each step could potentially remove a link.  That's likely to converge in `O(n log n)` on most real-world data, but I think has a worst case of `O(n^2)`.  Dang it.  By the way, someone with your algorithmic insight would really benefit from learning Haskell.  It's very easy to express these sorts of solutions.

Comment: Weird, when I actually ran your test case on my unmodified program it gave the right answer.  I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

I will try my hand at an answer, and fully expect to hear what's wrong with it soon. :)

So first, I think the problem may be more easily tackled by thinking of the pair of ranges instead as defining a rectangle. Suppose you have [(0,2), (3,4)]. Another way to view this is the rectangle in Cartesian coordinates of (0,3) to (2,4). Overlap of both ranges can then be thought of as rectangle-to-rectangle intersection.

With that in mind, I think a spatial structure is possibly most appropriate. The path my tired brain can conjure up is to use an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) or one of its variants. Finding the union of rectangles then becomes similar to building the tree. At each step, use the rectangle being added first as a search. If it finds any rectangles, replace all found rectangles with the "union" rectangle - the min/max of x/y coordinates, else add the rectangle as is. Once the tree is built, simply iterate through the rectangles and voila, convert them back to your ranges.

The unfortunate reality is that the runtime is not going to be easily analyzable. Let's note some of the potential issues:

- R-trees themselves do not guarantee good worst-case performance (as noted by Wikipedia)
- When adding a new rectangle, the number of overlapping rectangles plays a role in the complexity of the step. This seems to imply density is a sneaky factor.
- R-trees are likely complex enough that any constant factor is probably pretty high, which may mean that other methods win out depending on your data set size.

Given a large enough set, I believe this approach would win out. I believe it to be quadratic only in "bad" cases. But R-trees are not simple data structures, so it needs to be thought through carefully. Good luck!

Comment: With me being not familiar with R-tress and you writing these are not simple data structures, makes me think that this is too complicated for me. Maybe I'll try it when I understand these structures. Thanks for an answer!

Comment: Ah, well don't be scared by R-trees. I meant more that they're not simple on the inside but not that the API to use them isn't simple. I'm not a Python guy but [this](http://toblerity.org/rtree/tutorial.html) didn't look too hard if you're ever inclined to give it a shot.